# Binary Search program will compile and run but does not complete and won't terminate?

Tags: java, search, compilation, binary, terminate

I have written a binary Search program as part of a project. It will compile and run but when it gets to the part of the program where it should search the array for the target value (is entered by user) it doesn't do anything it just lets me enter a target value but does not appear to search or terminate.

Here is my code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
package ProofOfConcepts;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 * @author Kirome
 *
 */

public class BinarySearch {

    static int RandomNum;
    static int NumSize;
    static int[] arr;
    static int rangeOfNum;
    static int LookFor;
    static Random numGen = new Random();
    static Scanner Input = new Scanner(System.in);
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Enter the size of the data set");
        NumSize = Input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the range of the random numbers");
        rangeOfNum = Input.nextInt();
        arr = new int[NumSize];
        for (int i = 0; i <= NumSize-1; i++) {
            RandomNum = numGen.nextInt(rangeOfNum);
            arr[i] = RandomNum;
            System.out.println("Number is: " + RandomNum);  
        }
        System.out.println("Enter number you want to search for: ");
        LookFor = Input.nextInt();
        binarySearch(arr[0], arr.length-1, LookFor, arr);
    }
    //Binary Search Algorithm
    public static int binarySearch(int LowIndex, int HighIndex, int Target, int[] array) {
        int MidIndex = (LowIndex + HighIndex)/2;    
        while (LowIndex <= HighIndex) {
            if (array[MidIndex] == Target){
                System.out.println("Target is found at: " + array[MidIndex]);
                if (array[MidIndex] < Target){
                    binarySearch(LowIndex, MidIndex-1, Target, array);
                }
                if (array[MidIndex] > Target){
                    binarySearch(MidIndex+1, HighIndex, Target, array);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Target number is not in the array");
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(array);
        return Target;
    }
}
```

Its frustrating because I know it must be something simple to why it does not run properly. Thanks in advance, and p.s. I'm not the best programmer.

Comment: Add lots of logging until you can figure out when it starts doing something other than what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Firstly, your data should be sorted for binary search like @aring mentions below. Second, when you use recursion, you need to return the result --- so in the recursive call, you should have a `return binarySearch(MidIndex+1, HighIndex, Target, array)`

Comment: @Kal that should probably be an answer...

Comment: For binary search to work, your list of numbers must be sorted.  For example, if the input number is bigger than the middle value in the list, it only makes sense to look at the numbers in the top half of the array if those are the biggest numbers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to use binary search, you need sorted data.  Randomly distributed data cannot be searched with a binary search.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers, if the data is unsorted will binary search not work at all or will it just give unwanted results?

Comment: Behavior is essentially undefined.  It will probably give you an unwanted answer, but may in fact completely fail.  It shouldn't loop forever.

Comment: Thanks, when sorting the array I used the command Arrays.sort(arr); just after where I initialised the array with random numbers. but it hasn't sorted the array when I print it out, must it be sort another explicitly?                                                              Heres what I wrote:                                                  'code'for (int i = 0; i <= NumSize-1; i++) {
   RandomNum = numGen.nextInt(rangeOfNum);
   arr[i] = RandomNum;
   Arrays.sort(arr);
   System.out.println("Number is: " + RandomNum); 
  }'code'

Comment: Arrays.sort(arr) should sort the array in ascending order (assuming arr is int arr[] as above).  You need to use separate for loops.  Loop once to generate numbers.  Then out of the loop, call sort.  Then in another loop print values.

Comment: Thanks alot, you helped me out a bunch. Its the small things that I struggle to get used to in java.

Comment: Glad to help.  Keep at it!

Comment: Also, since you're a new member, it's always a good idea to select an accepted answer to your questions and vote on questions/answers which you feel are good.  This helps the reputation system work, which is the basis of the sites permission scheme.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting as an answer --

In addition to making sure that your input is sorted, the recursive binary search method should have returns in it so the method can correctly wind back the result to teh original call.

for instance -

```
if (array[MidIndex] < Target)
     return binarySearch(LowIndex, MidIndex-1, Target, array);
else if (array[MidIndex] > Target)
     return binarySearch(MidIndex+1, HighIndex, Target, array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the issue is the use of the while loop combined with recursion. Normally, if you are using recursion to implement a binary search, looping shouldn't be necessary.
Also, as others have said, make sure your array is sorted.

I would try this instead:

```
public static int binarySearch(int LowIndex, int HighIndex, int Target, int[] array) {     
    if (LowIndex <= HighIndex) {
        int MidIndex = (LowIndex + HighIndex)/2; 
        if (array[MidIndex] == Target){
            return Target;
        else if (Target < array[MidIndex])
            return binarySearch(LowIndex, MidIndex-1, Target, array);
        else 
            return binarySearch(MidIndex+1, HighIndex, Target, array);
    }

    return -1; // couldn't find target
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when sorting the array I used the command Arrays.sort(arr); just after where I initialised the array with random numbers. but it hasn't sorted the array when I print it out, must it be sort another explicitly?                                                              Heres what I wrote:                                                  for (int i = 0; i <= NumSize-1; i++) {

Comment: @user2152012 I assume you are generating a random number in that for loop and storing it in your array? Then after you are done filling your array, call the `Arrays.sort(..)` on your array.